# Adding a user-defined property to all types in D

Tags: types, casting, d, alias

I'm using Derelict for my OpenGL work, and I'm tired of having to `cast(GLvoid*) Vec3.sizeof` all the time for funclions like glVertexAttribPointer. So I thought I'd make a function, `glsizeof`

```
import std.stdio;

alias void GLvoid;

struct Vec3 {
    float x, y, z;
}

GLvoid* glsizeof(T)(T t) {
    return cast(GLvoid*) t.sizeof;
}

void main() {

    Vec3 vec = { x: 2.5, y: 4.8, z: 3.2 };

    writeln(cast(GLvoid*) vec.sizeof);  // prints 'C'
    writeln(cast(GLvoid*) Vec3.sizeof); // prints 'C'
    writeln(cast(GLvoid*) int.sizeof);  // prints '4'


    // Now to try using glsizeof :)

    GLvoid* size_vec  = vec.glsizeof;   // call glsizeof using a uniform function call
    GLvoid* size_vec3 = Vec3.glsizeof;
    GLvoid* size_int  = int.glsizeof;

    writeln(size_vec);  // should print 'C'
    writeln(size_vec3); // should print 'C'
    writeln(size_int);  // should print '4'
}
```

I get this error:

```
test.d(25): Error: no property 'glsizeof' for type 'Vec3'
test.d(26): Error: no property 'glsizeof' for type 'int'
```

Is there a way to add properties to types? Or can I do this another way, for example with an alias? Or is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Here's [the code](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/edit/5e7eb3f5) on DPaste.

*Edit: added some more detail on my expected output.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no. You can't pass types to functions, only templates, and if you want to add a property to something, you need to declare a property function.

However, since you *can* pass a type to a template, you can declare

```
template glsizeof(T)
{
    enum glsizeof = cast(GLvoid*)T.sizeof;
}
```

and then you can do

```
GLvoid* size_vec3 = glsizeof!Vec3;
GLvoid* size_int  = glsizeof!int;
```

So, as long as you're not picky about using the syntax `Type.glsizeof`, you have a solution. If you *are* picky about it, then sorry, but you're out of luck. You could define `glsizeof` for every type that you define. e.g.

```
struct S
{
    enum glsizeof = cast(GLvoid*)S.sizeof;
}
```

but that won't work for any types that you don't define, including the built-in types.

Comment: Cheers! I updated my use case (I should have put `GLvoid*` not `GLsizei`), but the answer remains the same. The alternatives aren't too bad - thanks for including them. :)

Comment: Okay. I updated my answer, but I'm actually a bit shocked that that works with a pointer, let alone `void*`. And casting a size to a pointer seems _really_ off to me, but I don't know anything about the API that you're using.

Comment: OpenGL being a C API has a ton of weird function parameters and that propagates over to the Derelict bindings. That's why I'm trying to abstract it away from most of my code.

Answer (score 2):

UFCS cannot current add static methods. See [this conversation](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/jrc1bm%241v2l%241@digitalmars.com) on the D newsgroup about it.